# Did Peter Pan, in the novel, kill every one of the lost boys as they showed signs of starting to grow up?

Tags: novel, peter-pan

Here is the passage I am referring to.

> All wanted blood except the boys, who liked it as a rule, but to-night were out to greet their captain. The boys on the island vary, of course, in numbers, according as they get killed and so on; and when they seem to be growing up, which is against the rules, Peter thins them out; but at this time there were six of them, counting the twins as two.

Did I misunderstand the meaning here?

Comment: Surely that's two unrelated clauses? "as they get killed" [in the course of fighting Hook etc] and "as Peter thins them out" [in some unspecified way, eg returning them to the mainland]?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think you've hit on the core of the question.

Comment: There's a fair amount of speculation that one of the reasons the pirates don't decrease in number over time is that the Lost Boys join them as they grow up. The book does make it clear that Peter will fight (and likely kill) the Lost Boys when the pirates are losing, because he finds it makes the fight "more interesting".

Comment: Even if you ignore the "they get killed", it says "Peter thins them out" — so what does he do to thin them out?

Comment: @shim: Death or exile would be my guesses.

Comment: Will have to check again, but I kinda remember something about Peter actually dropping them in the sea to drown. But I could be wrong or it could be something from the original unedited manuscript.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding that first sentence. Not sure if it's worth asking a separate question.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - There's nothing from the original text to suggest that, but it's mentioned in the 'official sequel' that some Lost Boys do become pirates. I think the assumption comes from the end of the original novel where the boys take over the ship and play pirate on it "*...that morning they were all stirring their stumps; for there was a big sea running; and Tootles, the bo’sun, was among them, with a rope’s end in his hand and chewing tobacco. They all donned pirate clothes cut off at the knee, shaved smartly, and tumbled up, with the true nautical roll and hitching their trousers.*"

Comment: @SPArcheon - I don't recall that and I've read a fair amount of versions of this. Maybe one of the lesser-known parodies?

Comment: @Valorum It may have also been from a cartoon/live action adaptation, because that's how I remember thinking it went when I was a kid without having read any version.

Comment: @Clockwork The first sentence explains how the boys would normally be out for blood with everyone else. But on this particular night they felt it more important to celebrate Peter's return. Rephrased: "we'll help you get revenge tomorrow, but tonight's a party".

Comment: It was always my understanding that the Lost Boys were boys who had *already died*, and that other than Wendy's group the way you got to Neverland was by dying young. That might make the clause "according as they get killed" refer to the method by which their numbers *grow*, and not the method by which they decrease; new Lost Boys arrive as new young boys die, somewhere in the real world.

Comment: @tbrookside I don't think so. In the book Peter says that they Lost Boys "are the children who fall out of their perambulators when the nurse is looking the other way. If they are not claimed in seven days they are sent far away to the Neverland to defray expenses. I’m captain." There are no girls because girls "are much too clever to fall out of their prams".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is clear as day,

### Yes.  Either killed or in some way "eliminated".

The sentence (sentences are delimited by semi-colons) is:

> "; and when they seem to be growing up [] Peter thins them out;

"thins them out" means and can only mean and has only ever meant "cull".

The clear and obvious meaning (kill) is the only meaning I have ever seen "thins them out" used by for example farmers or hunters - kill a few of 'em.

But sure, it could be a (dark!) humorous way of referring to, say, "exiled" or "sent to some other realm".

(a) The structure of the sentence is crystal-clear. The other two sentences, before and after the matching pair of semi-colons, have nothing to do with the issue.

(b) The meaning of that idiom is very well established and usage of the idiom is common and ubiquitous

### The specific question:

> Did I misunderstand the meaning here?

No.

Like any ribald and fantastical period children's story, it is **packed with slaughter, typically horrific, from beginning to end**.

Just as in classic-era "cowboys and indians" movies, and indeed small-children's movies like say Star Wars, minor characters get killed left right and center, usually brutally. (They thrown their hands up dramatically and drop down dead, like in any traditional western or war movie.)

Pan's body count of disposable "pirates" etc in the story is Terminator-like.

(In the Disney classic film, they (of course, obviously) did not indicate the incomprehensibly gruesome end of Hook, they just have him run off.)

Leaving aside answering the question, general thematic chat ...

### Don't forget it's a dream-like fantasy, rather like an author toying with characters in a book.

If Pan "kills" one or two of them (or indeed when Pan gaily slaughters pirates), it makes me think of an author "killing off" characters, or little boys playing "war" and falling down "dead"; the whole thing is a fantastical nonsense, like say Alice in Wonderland.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, it just repeats it in the form of a statement.

Comment: cheers @Valorum - how do you mean?  The question is answered simply:  (Issue 1) there seems to be some misunderstanding about the nearby sentences being related to the sentence with the phrase in question. I fully clarified this.  (Issue 2) There seems to be some confusion about what the idiom "thins them out" means. I fully clarified that.  The OP was clearly asking an, lets put it this way, ***"English language and meaning question***, which I answered. The text is the text and the Q is about the text. There was a lot of confusion so I explained it.

Comment: The other answers are more general chat about themes etc.  As an example, say someone asks what does this word or phrase mean in Shakespeare (common since it's archaic) the answer would not be a discussion on the themes and motives in the play, it's an "unravel these sentences" question - IMO !

Comment: Although the dictionary definition is  "To cull by killing", when it comes to a children's novel we can't always take things in their most literal sense. And that was what OP was asking. Not what it means, but what it *means*.

Comment: @Valorum I am sorry to disagree, but killing is completely commonplace in children's storytelling, particularly anything fantastical (which is .. most children's storytelling). Off with his head. Grimm. Potter.  Etc. Note that (of course, and obviously) ANY utterance in English can be sarcastic or humorous even darkly humorous: you can imagine a parent of 7 or 8 kids saying (very darkly!) "So many kids in this house, I have to thin them out!!" and then when everyone goes "DAAAD!!!!" adding "err, by marrying them off!".

Comment: I expanded on this in the thematic-chat part of the answer thanks to your prompting, ty

Comment: “Thin out” doesn’t translate directly to “kill” though, it just means to decrease in size. Why would Peter kill his friends rather than send them back to the regular world?

Comment: *'Why would Peter kill his friends'* Why would Peter be friends with a grown-up? He doesn't even remember Tinkerbell or Hook, he's not going to remember the boys who broke the rules by growing up into men and provoking his ire.

Comment: @Valorum This is a much better answer than a copy-paste from Wikipedia citing only a couple of derivative works by different authors.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - This is the sort of assertive '*my interpretation is*' answer that I'd expect to find favour on Lit:SE. or Yahoo Answers, but not somewhere like here that has higher standards.

Comment: @Valorum A *well-argued* interpretation makes for a much stronger answer than a M&TV-style Wiki copy-paste that says nothing definitive about Barrie's original work.

Comment: It has been a while since I read Peter Pan and Wendy, but isn't Peter a hero who kills pirates in honorable combat? I don' think the genre allows him to deliberately kill anyone who is not holding a weapon. I find it hard to accept that the bland "thin out" phrase covers a whole subplot in which he quarels with each boy who shows signs of adulthood, they fight to the death, and Peter always wins.

Comment: @David42 could it be you're wildly over thinking the logic of a (totally fantastical, surrealist, dada-ist) fairy tale?  Literally every fairy tale is stacked with death and torture, this "modern fairy tale" (maybe the "last fairy tale" before let's say modernism?) is no different.  And  it's no "sub plot" it's just an off-hand hilarious comment in the course of storytelling.

Comment: That’s my point. To suppose that Peter Pan has a scheme to liquidate children on the verge of adulthood is to overthink the story. Neverland isn’t John Carter’s Mars or Star Trek. It’s an allegorical place where children’s fantasies of adventure with weapons come alive. And it is a children’s play group. Lost Boys can decide to fight as Indians today and the real Indians agree to fight as Lost Boys. The two claimed causes of attrition reflect the dual aspects of Neverland. The fantasy says some boys will be killed. Reality says they will be “thinned out” of the play group as they outgrow it.

Answer (score 26):

Barrie doesn't explain what's meant by this. The implication is that they were *killed or banished*, but the text doesn't dwell on the matter or offer any further explanation.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan) offer some thoughts on the matter, referencing the Stage Play and the '*officially authorised*' sequel. Canonically, we learn, **Peter banishes them when they get too old.**

> Peter is the leader of the Lost Boys, which include Tootles, Nibs,
> Slightly, Curly, and The Twins. The Lost Boys is a band of boys who
> were lost by their parents after they "fall out of their
> perambulators" and came to live in Neverland. In Barrie's novel Peter
> and Wendy (but not the original play Peter Pan), it is stated that
> Peter "thins them out" when they start to grow up. This is never fully
> explained, but it is implied that he either kills them or banishes
> them.
>
> In the song "I Won't Grow Up" from the [1954 musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan_(1954_musical)), the boys sing *"I
> will stay a boy forever"*, to which Peter replies *"And be banished if I
> don't"*.
>
> > 
>
> In *[Peter Pan in Scarlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan_in_Scarlet)* (2006), the official sequel to Barrie's Peter
> and Wendy, what happens to the Lost Boys when they begin to grow up is
> revealed when Slightly starts to grow older, as Peter banishes him to
> Nowhereland (which means that he and all his allies will ignore the
> banished person's existence), the home of all the Long Lost Boys whom
> Peter has banished in times past.
>
> > *The valet’s voice was not quarrelsome. It remained as gentle and springy as a lamb. ‘Why would any sweetness linger, miss? Consider. Neglected and mislaid by their mothers, they are posted away to Neverland, their hearts in their boots. But—oh! the blessed relief!—they find themselves welcomed into the cosiness of den and tree house, into a world of friends and fun. They belong again! Life is perfect! Then one day their wrist-bones poke out below their cuffs; their trousers are too short. And for this sin they lose their place in Paradise. They are banished—put out-of-doors like an empty milk-bottle—despised and rejected—and this time by their very best friend.’*
>
> <sub><sup>[Peter Pan in Scarlet](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34264.Peter_Pan_in_Scarlet)</sup></sub>

Comment: Obviously both of these sources post-date Barrie's death and he had no direct hand in them.

Comment: With banishing them, would this be where all the adult pirates originate from? So they get banished, start growing older, forget their lost boys days, and turn to piracy as the way to live?

Comment: @TimBJames or remember them perfectly well and that's why they are out to kill the heartless and ruthless Peter who kicked them out of the only home they ever knew?

Comment: @Valorum True, but the 1954 lyrics are evidence of how the matter was perceived 70 years ago. It also is what makes most sense. The whole idea of the story is that Neverland is the fantasies of small children to which adults cannot return.

Answer (score 3):

Never-Never land is a playground for young children. When they grow up, they move on to other playgrounds.

When your children die young, as J M Barries brother did, a part of you remembers then "as they were"

> They shall grow not old, as we that are left grow old:
> Age shall not weary them, nor the years condemn.
> At the going down of the sun and in the morning
> We will remember them.
> <sub>"For the Fallen," Laurence Binyon</sub>

But a part of you also follows them as they "grow up" in your imagination.

> “When someone loses a spouse, they lose not just the person they spend every day with, but the person they’re planning on spending the next 40 years or more with. So they’re losing all those events they imagined in their future — the birth of their first grandchild, the day they celebrate their retirement together, or their 50th wedding anniversary,” Robinaugh said.

> “Our sense is that people with complicated grief continue to imagine those events. They continue to picture what their life would have been, and they deeply yearn for that counterfactual future,” he said. “It’s a future that’s no longer possible. But it’s one they still strongly, strongly desire, so when we ask them to imagine these events, they are readily able to do so.” (Richard McNally)

Peter Pan "thins out" the children as they age out, because he's in charge of the playschool. They move on to sports and theatre, and the dreams of school-age tweeners.

Comment: Is there a source from the author or canon for this claim, or are you simply making things up? I could not find a source for your claims when I went poking around.